# Can't find com.google.android.maps in Eclipse

Tags: android, maps

My Eclipse project is not able to find the class, I can only create it. I added this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>  
    <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

So I thought it would work now? ;) Also installed any SDK, downloaded nearly 40mins now

Comment: what sort of error do you get?  note also that you need to include <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> after </application>  (Including the complete manifest my be helpful for this issue)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to Project -> Properties -> Android, make sure the Project Build Target you have selected is one of the Google APIs ones (downloaded by the SDK manager under the "Third-Party Add-Ons" section).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Google API ,Follow this step to add google API in eclipse
[image]

[image]

Comment: Cab you please describe your method and way to save all the content on SDCARD?